# Cant fathom how to do this...PHP/Mysql question

Tags: php, mysql

Using php to get results from a database using

$exe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `info` ORDER BY `ID` ASC");

echo 'table width="80%"';

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($exe)) {

Then the table layout. So I am just getting a long long list of results. Is there anyway to after every 10 results make a break or put a line across?

Answer (score 5):

Use a counter and the modulus operator to put something every 10 rows:

```
$i = 0;
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($exe)) != null) {
  // print the row
  if (++$i % 10 == 0) {
    echo '<tr><td><hr></td></tr>';
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the != null, null is a falsy value in PHP so when $row == null the while loop will break.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).